# Does NTFS (or any file system) support files outside of the partition?

Tags: filesystems, ntfs, sectors, bootsector

So on my *C:* drive, there was a file called *BOOTSECT.BAK*. Not knowing what it is, I opened it up in *HxD* and the first 14 bytes were `B \0 O \0 O \0 T \0 M \0 G \0 R \0` corresponding to the UTF-16LE string `BOOTMGR`. After some research, I found out this is the VBR for Windows. This is installed onto sector 63 (or 2048 on Vista+).

After more research, it turns out to be a *copy* of the VBR, not the actual thing. That confused me as I am pretty sure I heard somewhere that Windows gives it its own file somewhere in `C:\Windows\System32` or `C:\Windows\boot`. I also heard that Windows assigns the *MBR* a file in one of those directories.

TL;DR: *Can NTFS (or any other file system for that matter) assign a file outside of the partition?* Most likely with negative integers or LBA of the start sector (i.e. -2048 for sector offset or 2048 for LBA)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Does NTFS (or any file system) support files outside of the partition?
```

Not that much on Windows but on Unix variants, and depending on how you define what a file is, you'll find file systems supporting files outside the partition.

- tmpfs support files stored partially or totally in RAM.
- procfs contains files in /proc/pid/fd/ that definitely belong to other file systems
- in /dev (or /devices) you have "files" which content is outside the partition. You can access the VBRs and MBRs through them (eg: /dev/sda1, /dev/dsk/c0d0t0p1, ...).
- All file systems supporting symbolic links can also sort of store files from foreign locations.

It looks like installing [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) will provide a [/dev directory](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-specialnames.html#pathnames-posixdevices) from which you would be able to access full disk and partition raw data including the VBRs and MBRs.

Comment: Even so, those directories are just mount-points under another filesystem as I mentioned previously.  Accessing files and sub-directories under those mount-points completely bypasses the filesystem one level up (i.e. I mount my main EXT4 FS at `/`, and mount my RAMDISK at `/tmp`, the files in `/tmp` have nothing to do with the EXT4 FS, just the RAMDISK one).  This is the same thing as mount-points under Windows.

Comment: @Breakthrough tmpfs, procfs and symbolic links were just examples. The real answer is /dev. Its entries are not at all mount-points. They are files of a special kind (character and block devices) containing data outside the current file system and one of these start with an UTF-16LE encoded BOOTMGR in Cole's case.

Answer (score 6):

> Can NTFS (or any other file system for that matter) assign a file
>   outside of the partition?

No, wouldn't that completely void the purpose of a filesystem to begin with?  If you just want to manipulate the raw 0's and 1's stored on the disk outside your partition, there's plenty of low-level disk operation tools you can use.  You can also mount another partition within a mounted NTFS partition (i.e. you can mount *another* partition at `C:\MyNewVol\`), if the files are stored within another filesystem.

Those particular files you outlined above are called [metafiles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Metafiles), and are well defined per the NTFS specification.  See that previous link for a description of various metafiles (e.g. the VBR you mentioned is stored in the `$Boot` metafile), and where they are located on-disk with respect to the NTFS partition boundaries.

Also, with respect to the whole MBR vs. VBR, from [the Wikipedia page on VBR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_boot_record):

> **[The VBR] is the first sector of an individual partition** on the
>   device, with the **first sector of the entire device being a master boot
>   record (MBR)** containing the partition table.

Thus, you can access the VBR through the NTFS filesystem (assuming you have the proper permissions to do so), but you can't directly access the MBR; for that, you *do* need low-level disk tools.

Answer (score 1):

Filesystems only address data inside their own allocated space.

However an operating system has no such limitations and it can stores information read from anywhere on the disk in a file.

The distinction between the OS and the FS might be small, but it is vital.